# Use d3.json function with variable instead of URL

Tags: d3.js

Hello I have a jquery ajax call that returns json data from an api.

I turned that json into a variable and want to use it in `d3.json`.

It isnt taking the variable name, I think because its expecting a url instead of a variable name.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: myurl.com,
    success: function(effects)
    {
        var dataArray = effects;

            d3.json(dataArray, function (data) { //error here
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
});
```

Those of you good with d3, can you help me get the json data into the `d3.json` function?

Thanks

Comment: I think there is a slight misconception on what both methods actually do. [`d3.json()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json) is not just for parsing; it will request the JSON resource **and** parse it, whereas `jQuery.ajax()` only requests the resource without parsing it. When using `jQuery.ajax()` you need to use the native [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the JSON string, **not** `d3.json()`**!

Comment: oh! makes sense now, thank you for the explanation

Comment: `d3.json` already does the AJAX request for you, so I'd just use that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the data from API which you called effects. I suppose that the effects are in json format like "key":"value" paires, you can try 
var jsonVariable = effects["key"] to get the value.